# Permission of all applications installed in a Preference

Tags: java, android, xml, permissions

I have a problem. I would like to create a PreferenceActivity where there are for each application installed in the device relative Preference and Summary written the various permissions that the application requires. I wrote this code, but it does not work because when I start the application not display anything.

```
public class Permission extends PreferenceActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.permission);       

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
       Preference preference = new Preference(this);
       preference.setTitle(applicationInfo.packageName);

       try {
          PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

          //Get Permissions
          String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

          if(requestedPermissions != null) {
             for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                preference.setSummary(requestedPermissions[i]);
             }
          }
       } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
}
```

The layout is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



</PreferenceScreen>
```

I apologize if the question may seem stupid but I'm going crazy to find a solution. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "I wrote this code, but it does not work because when I start the application not display anything" -- off the cuff, that is because you are creating `Preference` objects, then doing nothing with them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. How do I do nothing? I assign the title and the summary to the created preference!

Comment: But then you don't put that `Preference` object anywhere. It exists, but is not added to anything.